# VB.NET Memory Leak with Event Handler?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, memory-leaks

I have VB.NET solution that consists of two projects.  One is a DLL, and the other is a Form app that utilizes the DLL.  The form app has a event that gets fired about 200K times a day.  I have confirmed that this event is eating up memory that will not go away.  Did a bit of googling, and it says the fix for event memory leaks is to utilize Weak References.

Can someone dumb down how this works?  All the examples I've found are in C# where you have to subscribe to the event.  What about in VB.NET where it's handled during design?   Below is the event that is causing my memory leak.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplAttribute(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)> 
Private Sub Engine1_AGIReady(ByVal Channel As Integer, ByVal Server As Integer, ByVal CallResult As String, ByVal Arg1 As String) Handles Engine1.AGIReady
    ScriptHandle.Process(Channel, Server, CallResult, Arg1)



End Sub
```

For some reason I cannot wrap my head around "Weak References", how it solves the memory leak, and how to apply it to my solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or do you need to remove the delegate with `RemoveHandler` clause? We may need more info here. Does it need to fire that much or is it just firing cause nothing is turning it off?

Comment: Are there any collections or class variables adding info with each event firing?

Comment: It's a TCP program.  The event gets triggered everytime a tcp connection is made.  The variables being passed are simple variables as you can see in the event declaration.  Those variables are then used to reference collections inside the DLL.

Comment: You need to determine the root cause of the memory leak. What is going on inside of `ScriptHandle.Process`? What objects are consuming memory? We can't tell you anything based on what you've shown us.

Comment: Well, start pouring over `ScriptHandle.Process` for anything that could be holding memory and make sure you only subscribe to your event once or are unsubscribing as needed. Objects will not free up if their events are still subscribed to.

Comment: ScriptHandle.Process creates threads, and thats it.  Based off of previous reading, once a thread gets to EoL (End of Life), any objects the thread consumes are definitely released via GC. . . correct?

Comment: Looking over at my ScriptHandle class, I noticed that I have a reference to the main form that I am not releasing.  I am going to make adjustments with the code to make sure that gets released.  Gut feeling is that this is not going to fix it.  We'll see what happens tommorrow.

Comment: I was using RedGate's memory profiler.  It states (ThreadContext) is the memory leak.  After research it, I am assuming that it's my event.  RedGate was able to pin point another memory leak that I fixed a couple of days ago, and it was able to point out references like my form as being the issue.  This particular issue (ThreadContext), is not very descriptive.  That's why my gut feeling says it's not the form reference in the class.